# CORS blocking localhost request despite being explicitly allowed

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, socket.io, cors

I have a NodeJS (Express + Socket.io) server running backend with a React frontend. My React is running on localhost:3000 whereas my backend runs on port 4000. I've explicitly allowed CORS requests to be made to my Socket.IO server:

```
const express = require('express')
const { createServer } = require("http");
const cors = require('cors')
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')
const {connectDB} = require('./config/db');
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000
require('dotenv').config()

connectDB()

//TEST logic for creating local list
const usersWaiting = []

//initialize Socket.io server
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {origin: "http://localhost:3000", methods: ["GET"]}
});

//configure everything, define routes
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use('/user', require('./routes/userRoute'))
app.use(errorHandler)
 
//set 404
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send('Not found.')
})

//start the listening
httpServer.listen(port, () => {console.log(`Server started on port ${port}.`)})
```

And in my React frontend I do a simple **async onClick** with this in it to test:

```
console.log(await fetch('http://localhost:4000/user'))
```

And the error I receive:

**Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:4000/user' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.**

Now I know, I know, this question's been asked a few times. However I've read 15 answers and implemented literally every single one of your advices. Nothing works.

I feel like I'm going crazy - please help!

Comment: `app.use(cors(…))`

Comment: tried that @Robertklep , unfortunately doesn't change anything.

Answer (score -1):

Try by adding proxy in react app `package.json`,

```
package.json 
{
 ...,
 ...,
 "proxy": "http://localhost:4000"
}
```

Comment: That does fix the CORS error! However when I then change my fetch() to fetch("/user/"), it then responds with a 200 OK without body. Even though if I directly browse to localhost:4000/user I see a test object which it is supposed to return.